# association through many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :albums

end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :songs

end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :albums

end
```

I need to determine which user a specific song belongs to on a regular basis. Is it better form to add a belongs_to :user relationship in the Song model or to call song.album.artist.user every time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're violating the [Law of Demeter](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/). Consider using `delegate`:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :albums
  delegate :user, :to => :album

end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :songs
  delegate :user, :to => :artist

end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :albums

end
```

With this method, you can now call `song.user`

An additional benefit, here, is if the structure of your model changes (which it probably will), you can re-define or re-delegate `Song#user` to something else so that objects that depend on calling `song.user` won't break.

### Resources

- http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/
- http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: how would the routes look for these models??

Comment: You will want to use shallow routes. See section 3.7.4: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=7